# Shortcut for function parameter tooltip

Tags: swift, xcode

In Swift, when I start using some function, I get a tooltip with description of parameters. But when I start typing, it disappears and I have no idea how to call it after that.

What is the shortcut to call this function parameter tool tip again?

A few image on what I want.

When I, for example, create `UIAlertController` and press `(`, XCode will show this

[image]

Now, if you select and ENTER function, it will autocomplete parameters names and let you input values.

But if you **start typing the 1st parameter name and value**, then add comma, XCode will not show this tooltip to help you know the name of the next parameter

[image]

And in this case I would like to know the shortcut to call the tooltip with the name of the next parameter.

If I hit `escape`, it does not help as well. I even navigated to the exact param name, but XCode did not recognize it.

[image]

PS. This is the same command as CTRL + P in Android Studio.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you mean?

Comment: Are you looking for Autocomplete in Xcode? If it is true, the shortcut is Control + Space.

Comment: Sometimes Xcode Autocomplete does not work. "It should be just temporary issue: Clean your build / build folder, reopen Xcode. It ensures your code will be indexed again and this is used to result in quick syntax highlighting and smart suggestion features."

Refer to here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550552/code-completion-drop-down-suggestions-not-working-properly-xcode-8-0-swift-3?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Check my edit.

Comment: @TrungAnhPham Check my edit

Comment: Just hit escape.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth It does not work as well. Check the new edit. Is works in your case? In my case, XCode was unable to recognize this simple test use case.

Comment: The Xcode autocompletion is kind of unpredictable. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Just select the function you want to use and fill in the placeholders. You can also try to use Xcode 9. I have used it for some time now and even though it is only the first beta, the editor seems to work much better than Xcode 8. (Also you get refactoring for Swift)

Comment: Definitely second that! Xcode 9‘s editor seems re-written in quite a few ways. Works muuuuch better!